# Im trying to make an app that searches files from Firebase and I am getting this error

Tags: java, android, firebase

The Error

> 'FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions<com.munopa.revise.Files>)'
> in 'com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter' cannot be
> applied to '(java.lang.Class<com.munopa.revise.Files>, int,
> java.lang.Class<com.munopa.revise.MainActivity.FilesViewHolder>,
> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference)'

My Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mSearchField;
private RecyclerView mFileList;
private FloatingActionButton mSearchButton;
private DatabaseReference mFilesDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mFilesDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Files");

    mSearchField = findViewById(R.id.search_bar_input);
    mFileList = findViewById(R.id.file_list);
    mSearchButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_search);

    mSearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            firebaseFileSearch();
        }
    });
}

private void firebaseFileSearch() {
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Files, FilesViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Files, FilesViewHolder>(
            Files.class,
            R.layout.paper_card,
            FilesViewHolder.class,
            mFilesDatabase
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FilesViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Files model) {

        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public FilesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return null;
        }
    };
}

public class FilesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;

    public FilesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem (and where you are getting the error):

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Files, FilesViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
    new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Files, FilesViewHolder>(
        Files.class,
        R.layout.paper_card,
        FilesViewHolder.class,
        mFilesDatabase
)
```

You are calling the constructor of `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` with 4 parameters, but it only expects 1 parameter of type `FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Files>`.

Refer to https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md for more details about how to set this up.